# Change Chapter 1 to Chapter ONE

Tags: chapters

I am writing thesis that the format is CHAPTER ONE. My template display CHAPTER 1. How to change the template?

The codes that I have right now is like the following:

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}[3][]{%
\setcounter{chapter}{#3}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\chapter*{#2}
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
\else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\fi
}

\newcommand{\setupname}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{%
   % \renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
      \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{#1 }%
      \setlength\cftchapnumwidth{\widthof{\bfseries #1 }}%
      \addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\fixedchapnumwidth}%
      \renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{\vspace{0.6em}: \vspace{0.8em}}
    }}%
  }%
}


\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{-0.2em}}

%\setcounter{page}{1}
  %\titlespacing*{\chapter}{10pt}{0pt}{10pt}
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
      {\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}{ \chaptertitlename\ \NUMBERstring{\thechapter}}{{}10pt}{\large}

\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{roman}  % to put the romman number lower letters
% begin for remove page number from table of content for chapter only not sections
\newcommand{\gobbletocpage}{%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
    \addtocontents{##1}{\protect\contentsline{##2}{##3}{\relax}}}
}%


\pagenumbering{roman}
\setupname{CHAPTER}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par} % to add page at top of TABLE OF CONTENT  page numbering
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em} % to remove space before table of content
\renewcommand\contentsname{\large \textbf{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{TABLE OF CONTENTS}} %{\vspace{-5em}}%
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\clearpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{2.0em}}
\input main/chap1.tex
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{2.0em}}
\input main/chap2.tex
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{2.0em}}
%\input main/lang.tex
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{2.0em}}
\input main/chap3.tex
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{2.0em}}
\input main/chap4.tex
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{2.0em}}
\input main/chap5.tex
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{2.0em}}
\input main/chap7.tex



\end{document}
```